# Convert multidimensional arrays to json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

how do I make json values ​​like this in c #?

please help me make the c # code line to get the value json like this

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      50291, 
      7410, 
      2013, 
      2013, 
      524, 
      201
    ], 
    "name": "project1"
  },
{
    "data": [
      50291, 
      7410, 
      2013, 
      2013, 
      524, 
      201
    ], 
    "name": "project2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Newtonsoft's library this is trivial. Use the following code to go from json string to object and from object back to a json string.

```
void Main()
{
    var myJson = "[{\"data\": [50291, 7410, 2013, 2013, 524, 201], \"name\": \"project1\"}, {\"data\": [50291, 7410, 2013, 2013, 524, 201], \"name\": \"project2\"}]";

    var myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyData>>(myJson);

    var myJsonAgain = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);    
}

public class MyData
{
    public List<Int32> Data { get; set; }
    public String Name { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: I mean from c# to json

Comment: Yes, the example above does both.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link to generate class structure

http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Create an `obj = List<RootObject>` and assign your value for it.

Use SerializeObject   `var mystring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)`